# Rendering changes to html templates using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to use python's flask api and javascript to build a web application. As a simple example I wanted to have a text input box that will print the users input after they submit. However, when I run this using flask run and input some text nothing changes except that I get redirected from "/5000" to "/5000/?input=text" where text is the user input.

Why don't I see "You wrote: text" below the input box?

My code looks something like this:

**app.py:**

```
@app.route('/')
def render_home():
    return render_template("base.html")
```

**update.js:**

```
function update() {
    var new_input = document.getElementById("input");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + new_input.value;
}
```

**base.html:**

```
<body>
<form>
    <label for="input">Example Input:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="input" onchange="update()"><br>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/update.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

So Flask is registering the 'submit' as a GET request, which is why it's appearing in the URL. if you're hoping to have this information parsed in the backend you can use the `request` submodule so to actually recieve the data by the Python instance, using something like `request.args` to receive it as a key: value pair.

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def render_home():
    req = request.args
    print(req)
    return render_template("base.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the app adds the query param when you press Enter, but I think your JS function is not working because `getElementById('input')` will return `null` since your input has no id set on it.
Try setting the id on the input like `<input id="myInput"` and use `document.getElementById('myInput')`

Also you have a typo in the JS func. Your input is in `new_input` but you are using `new_factor` later.

Comment: You are absolutely correct I accidentally used name= instead of id=! After making that change and running again it kind of works. When I press enter the words "You wrote: text" now briefly appear then disappear right away. Any idea why they don't stay there until a new input is provided bc that is more along the lines of what i want

Comment: When you press enter, the page reloads because it's sending a GET request. Anything you've done with JS will be removed, since it's not stored on the server side. See the answer from Michael Green below on how to catch the arguments from the request string.

Comment: Ah and the JS func typo is only here where I changed the name of the var when copying my code but forgot to change the second appearance

Comment: yeah, the js func only runs on the `onchange` event of the input and it only runs in the browser. If you want the "demo" box to reflect the input value when submitting the form without using ajax requests, you should pass the request string params to the template

Comment: So does that mean I'll need something in flask to handle the GET request if I want the change to persist after I hit 'enter'?